# Jquery : how to get the parent <tr> using its <td> value?

Tags: jquery

I have a table structure which is dynamically generated like this -

```
    <table>
    <tr class="row">
    <td class="order">1</td>
    <td class="name">abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
    <td class="order">2</td>
    <td class="name">def</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Basically I will be having  values 1,2 of both the rows.Using each order value, how will I be able to get its parent  and loop through it and get that 's  value ?

Output that I'm expecting is using order value "1", I must get "abc" and using order value "2", I must get "def" .

Can anyone help me out with the solution for this ?

Comment: have you tried anything???

Comment: The parent would be the TR, and it has no value, neither has any of the other elements ?

Comment: Yes i have tried using this - $.each(orders, function( index, value ) {
    var ordervalue = value;
    var row = $(this).parent('tr').find(".name").html();
   });

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var value = ;// 1 or 2 etc
var text  = $('.row td.order').filter(function(){
   return $.trim($(this).text()) == value
}).next().text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next()` to get the next td, first you need to bind the event to td contain values 1, 2. You can use .row class and bind event to its descendant td in selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68478/2/)**

```
$('.row td.order').click(function(){
   alert($(this).next().text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this method as well

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is always like in your example, you could use `next()` like this:

```
var order = 1;
$('.row td.order:contains('+order+')').next().text()
```

If not you could use this (explicitly search for 'name' td):

```
var order = 1;
$('.row td.order:contains('+order+')').parent().find("td.name").text()
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTRVL/)